# ContextualCompressionRetriever.get_relevant_documents() is throwing Error when trying to get relevant documents

Tags: python, machine-learning, openai-api, langchain, amazon-bedrock

So, I have created a compression_retriever as such

```
retriever=db.as_retriever(search_kwargs=search_kwargs)
compressor = LLMChainFilter.from_llm(llm)
compression_retriever = ContextualCompressionRetriever(base_compressor=compressor, base_retriever=retriever)
```

Here llm used is:

```
llm = Bedrock(model_id="anthropic.claude-v2", client=bedrock_client)
```

Now when I am trying to retrieve the relevant documents using 'answer' in this way

```
compressed_docs = compression_retriever.get_relevant_documents(answer)
```

I am getting an error saying:

```
An error occurred BooleanOutputParser expected output value to either be YES or NO
```

But, with the set the LLM as OpenAI 3.5 it works fine.

I tried going through the documentations but no solution seems to pop up.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a limitation of `anthropic.claude-v2`. Try using `anthropic.claude-v1` instead.